# What can be the possible benefits of analysing rare words?

Tags: nlp

A few days ago, I was assigned the task to analyse rare words for apparently anything but it needs to be novel. But, after reading articles and research papers and my previous NLP and Computer Science experience, I don't understand what benefits can be extracted in analysing rare except for NER and tokenization problem. And a few statistical problem such as cultural shift, etc.

Now, I am in a block and standstill state. If anyone could help with their more in-depth experience and insights it'll greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing rare words can indeed be a challenging task, but it can also be a very interesting one. I am adding few potential benefits and applications of analyzing rare words:

**Language Evolution**: Rare words can provide insights into how language evolves over time. For example, new words that are just starting to be used may initially be rare, but could become more common over time. By tracking these changes, we can learn more about how language changes and evolves.

**Semantic Analysis**: Rare words can also be important in semantic analysis. For example, in sentiment analysis, rare words might carry strong positive or negative connotations that could significantly impact the overall sentiment of a text.

**Cultural Studies**: Rare words can also provide insights into cultural trends and shifts. For example, the use of certain words might be associated with specific cultural movements or periods of history.

**Information Retrieval**: In information retrieval, rare words can be very useful. Because they are less common, they can help to narrow down search results and make it easier to find relevant information.

**Machine Learning**: In machine learning, rare words can be used to improve the performance of models. For example, by identifying and handling rare words appropriately, it might be possible to improve the accuracy of text classification models.

**Linguistic Diversity**: Analyzing rare words can help in understanding the diversity and richness of a language. It can help in preserving languages and in understanding the nuances of dialects and regional languages.

Remember, the rarity of a word doesn't diminish its importance. In fact, it can often make it more interesting and valuable to study.

Comment: thank you for your insights! I actually knew all of this and like I mentioned in my question description, I am well aware what NLP and statistical points are for analysing rare words. I asked the question to get to know about people's exotic opinions and thoughts on why rare words needs to be analysed in NLP or statistical Machine learning

Comment: People might have different thoughts, but I am just what I think as you asked for opinions, I am giving mine. I hope more people will have some insights. Cheers!